# JNI AttachNativeThread always fails with -1 return value on Linux

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, jnienv

I'm writing a JNI wrapper around a native C++ library, but I'm having trouble attaching native threads to the JVM on Linux. Everything works fine on Windows, but when I call AttachNativeThread() on an Ubuntu machine, it always returns -1.

This is the way I'm getting JNIEnv pointers:

```
JNIEnv* Utils::getJNI() {
    JNIEnv* jni;

    int getEnvResult = FMODWrapper::jvm->GetEnv((void**) &jni, JNI_VERSION_1_8);

    if (getEnvResult == JNI_EDETACHED) {
        JavaVMAttachArgs attachArgs;

        attachArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_8;
        attachArgs.group = nullptr;

        std::stringstream newName;
        newName << "jni-attached-daemon-" << std::this_thread::get_id();

        attachArgs.name = (char*) newName.str().c_str();

        int attachResult = FMODWrapper::jvm->AttachCurrentThreadAsDaemon(ANDROID_VOIDPP_CAST &jni, &attachArgs);

        if(attachResult != 0) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to attach thread! " << attachResult << "(" << newName.str() << ")" << std::endl;

        }
    }

    return jni;
}
```

I know that the JVM pointer is not null, and again, the code works flawlessly on Windows. If it's not possible to attach native threads on Linux for some reason, I'm always open to alternatives: the thing I'm trying to achieve are basically callbacks into my Java code. An event happens in C++, for example a request for File open, and I need to be able to handle that in Java.

Update: My JVM versions, both `java` and `javac`, this is what I used to compile and run the program.

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.10.1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
javac 1.8.0_191
```

Comment: What is ANDROID_VOIDPP_CAST? A `void *` cast isn't required here.

Comment: It's a macro that's set to `(void**)` on Android only

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your JVM on Linux is not Java 8 compatible. There is no reason to ask for JNI_VERSION_1_8 unless you use some Java 8 JNI features. Usually, JNI_VERSION_1_6 will suffice.

Comment: Wasn't it sadly, my JVM version is `OpenJDK 1.8.0_191`, using `JNI_VERSION_1_6` changed nothing. Didn't work with Oracle JVMs either

Answer (score 0):

See *[JNI Linux segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55790924/192373)*. This is the same problem with the same **FMODWrapper** when switching from Windows to Linux.

The root cause could be the logger that is used in your wrapper. As **[Lóránt Viktor Gerber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5453250/l%c3%b3r%c3%a1nt-viktor-gerber)** shows there, the logger is initialized with a local reference to **java/lang/System**. If this logger is somehow involved in `Utils::getJNI()`, it will fail.

Another suspicious part of your code is passing a temporary **name** to `AttachCurrentThreadAsDaemon()`. I would try to set it to **nullptr** to exclude any interference.

If all the above does not work, check if `AttachCurrentThreadAsDaemon()` (not as a daemon) still fails in your Linux environment.

Comment: I've now narrowed it down some more, with your suggestions it works whith my _own_ threads, however, the ones that FMOD creates still fail to attach.

Comment: Sadly, I have no idea where this FMOD comes from, and how its threads are created.

Comment: Probably the names, I did everything you said and new threads with `std::thread` now work, but the FMOD ones don't.