# Crashes in art::JNI::NewStringUTF()

Tags: java-native-interface, android-runtime

In my Google Play developer console, I see a lot of crashes in NewStringUTF() like so:

```
  #00  pc 00000000001b9f22  /system/lib/libart.so (art::IndirectReferenceTable::Add(art::IRTSegmentState, art::ObjPtr<art::mirror::Object>, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>*)+630)
  #01  pc 00000000002ad461  /system/lib/libart.so (_jthrowable* art::JNIEnvExt::AddLocalReference<_jthrowable*>(art::ObjPtr<art::mirror::Object>)+32)
  #02  pc 0000000000298e49  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::NewStringUTF(_JNIEnv*, char const*)+416)
  #03  pc 000000000024baf0  /data/app/com.steenriver.littlecrane-1vpoZWmGtL5mN2uxtEBltA==/lib/arm/liblittlecrane.so (androidsupport_reportFailedLaunch(char const*)+64)
  ...
```

So the actually crash is in IndirectReferenceTable::Add() call.

Why would the NewStringUTF() call fail?
I pass it a normal ASCII string, and my 'env' pointer is not null.

My code:

```
bool androidsupport_reportFailedLaunch( const char* msg )
{
        if ( !androidsupport_engine.app ) return false;

        JNIEnv* env = androidsupport_engine.app->appThreadEnv;
        if ( !env ) return false;

        jstring jniText = env->NewStringUTF( msg );
        EXCEPTION_RETURN( env );

        ...
```

The msg parameter is not nil, and points to a const char* that is in static memory, as the function is called like so:

```
androidsupport_reportFailedLaunch( "Incompatible device." );
```

The JNIEnv* is cached, but it was attached to the native thread like so:

```
    int error = (*android_app->activity->vm)->AttachCurrentThread(android_app->activity->vm, &android_app->appThreadEnv, NULL);
    if (error) android_app->appThreadEnv = NULL;
```

according to [an Android example by nvidia](https://github.com/NVIDIAGameWorks/GraphicsSamples/blob/master/extensions/src/NvAppBase/android/NvAndroidNativeAppGlue.c).

Comment: Maybe you've filled up the local reference table? Every call to `NewStringUTF` creates a new local reference. Do you ever delete those? Or does this thread return back to Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keeping a global reference to the JNIEnv environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420463/keeping-a-global-reference-to-the-jnienv-environment)

Comment: You **can not** cache the `JNIEnv *` value.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I do AttachCurrentThread() when I cache that JNIEnv, and it is only used by my NativeActivity thread.

Answer (score 0):

`NewStringUTF()` [accepts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#NewStringUTF) *[modified UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7921016/what-does-it-mean-to-say-java-modified-utf-8-encoding)*. Feel free to use `NewString()` to construct a regular Java String object as long as the input argument contains only ASCII characters.   As soon as it includes non-ASCII characters, manual conversion may be required.

Comment: I only feed it ASCII strings. Also, I doubt that if it contained any other characters, it would flat-out crash.

Comment: @Bram It *does* 'flat-out crash'.

Comment: NewString is for UTF-16. Nothing in Java/JNI/JVM is related to ASCII (except foreign character set encoding/decoding [StandardCharsets.US_ASCII](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html#US_ASCII)).

Comment: My point was that ASCII string is a valid UTF-8 string, but I forgot about `NewString()` accepting UTF-16, and not UTF-8.